# Unable to allocate 208. GiB for an array with shape (27939587241,) and data type int64?

Tags: python, pandas, out-of-memory

This is my code:

```py
play_count_with_title = pd.merge(df_count, df_small[['song_id', 'title', 'release']], on = 'song_id' )

final_ratings  = pd.merge(play_count_with_title, df_small[['song_id', 'artist_name']], on = 'song_id' )

final_ratings
```

the error which i got is

```
Unable to allocate 208. GiB for an array with shape (27939587241,) and data type int64
```

The Code which enabled this error within the library is

```
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:124, in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     93 @Substitution("\nleft : DataFrame or named Series")
     94 @Appender(_merge_doc, indents=0)
     95 def merge(
   (...)
    108     validate: str | None = None,
    109 ) -> DataFrame:
    110     op = _MergeOperation(
    111         left,
    112         right,
   (...)
    122         validate=validate,
    123     )
--> 124     return op.get_result(copy=copy)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:773, in _MergeOperation.get_result(self, copy)
    770 if self.indicator:
    771     self.left, self.right = self._indicator_pre_merge(self.left, self.right)
--> 773 join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
    775 result = self._reindex_and_concat(
    776     join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer, copy=copy
    777 )
    778 result = result.__finalize__(self, method=self._merge_type)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:1026, in _MergeOperation._get_join_info(self)
   1022     join_index, right_indexer, left_indexer = _left_join_on_index(
   1023         right_ax, left_ax, self.right_join_keys, sort=self.sort
   1024     )
   1025 else:
-> 1026     (left_indexer, right_indexer) = self._get_join_indexers()
   1028     if self.right_index:
   1029         if len(self.left) > 0:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:1000, in _MergeOperation._get_join_indexers(self)
    998 def _get_join_indexers(self) -> tuple[npt.NDArray[np.intp], npt.NDArray[np.intp]]:
    999     """return the join indexers"""
-> 1000     return get_join_indexers(
   1001         self.left_join_keys, self.right_join_keys, sort=self.sort, how=self.how
   1002     )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:1610, in get_join_indexers(left_keys, right_keys, sort, how, **kwargs)
   1600 join_func = {
   1601     "inner": libjoin.inner_join,
   1602     "left": libjoin.left_outer_join,
   (...)
   1606     "outer": libjoin.full_outer_join,
   1607 }[how]
   1609 # error: Cannot call function of unknown type
-> 1610 return join_func(lkey, rkey, count, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\join.pyx:48, in pandas._libs.join.inner_join()
```

As a beginner i dont understand the error can you guys help me out?

Comment: @Shrikanth_Krish How big is the file you analyze?

Comment: (154377, 7) is the shape

Comment: Whatever you did created a humongous amount of data.

Comment: Is `song_id` unique per dataframe? Im my experience if the join key is not unique, pandas will explode the tables (so a outer join). If it is the case, try to find a different join method or filter out noise before joinging

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what's going on without a sample of your data.  However, this looks like the sort of problem you'd see if there are a lot of duplicated values in both dataframes.

Note that if there are multiple rows which match during the merge, then every combination of left and right rows is emitted by the merge.

For example, here's a tiny example of a 3-element DataFrame being merged with itself.  The result has 9 elements!

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1], 'b': [1,2,3]})

In [8]: df.merge(df, 'left', on='a')
Out[8]:
   a  b_x  b_y
0  1    1    1
1  1    1    2
2  1    1    3
3  1    2    1
4  1    2    2
5  1    2    3
6  1    3    1
7  1    3    2
8  1    3    3
```

If your `song_id` column has a lot of duplicates in it, then the number of elements could be as many as N^2, i.e. `154377**2 == 23832258129` in the worst case.

Try using `drop_duplicates('song_id')` on each of the merge inputs to see what happens in that case.

Comment: But OP already got 27939587241. It's beyond the worst case. However, your calculation is almost close.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice, I have solved the problem.

Comment: @ConstantinHong Note that I'm referring to the number of rows (in the worst case), but the user's error refers to the number of bytes, which will always be higher.  Since I have no idea how many columns there are and what dtypes of the columns are, I can't calculate a worst-case number of bytes.

Comment: @StuartBerg, I learned this from you. Sincerely, Thank you!